# Getting the placeholder values with Open XML SDK 2.0

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to drill down through a shapetree in a PowerPoint slide to get a shape's placeholder values.  The shape on the shapetree looks like this:

```
<p:sp>
    <p:nvSpPr>
        <p:cNvPr id="10" name="Text Placeholder 2"/>
        <p:cNvSpPr>
            <a:spLocks noGrp="1"/>
        </p:cNvSpPr>
        <p:nvPr>
            <p:ph type="body" sz="quarter" idx="13" hasCustomPrompt="1"/>
        </p:nvPr>
    </p:nvSpPr>
    <p:spPr>
        <a:xfrm>
            <a:off x="457200" y="3276601"/>
            <a:ext cx="8229600" cy="838199"/>
        </a:xfrm>
        <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
            <a:avLst/>
        </a:prstGeom>
    </p:spPr>
    <p:txBody>
        <a:bodyPr lIns="91421" tIns="45710" rIns="91421" bIns="45710"/>
        <a:lstStyle>
            <a:lvl1pPr marL="0" indent="0" algn="ctr">
                <a:buFontTx/>
                <a:buNone/>
                <a:defRPr sz="2400" b="1" baseline="0">
                    <a:solidFill>
                        <a:schemeClr val="tx1"/>
                    </a:solidFill>
                    <a:latin typeface="+mj-lt"/>
                    <a:cs typeface="Arial" pitchFamily="34" charset="0"/>
                </a:defRPr>
            </a:lvl1pPr>
        </a:lstStyle>
        <a:p>
            <a:pPr lvl="0"/>
            <a:r>
                <a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0" smtClean="0"/>
                <a:t>Click to enter course title</a:t>
            </a:r>
        </a:p>
    </p:txBody>
</p:sp>
```

The part I'm interested in getting looks like this:

```
<p:nvPr>
    <p:ph type="body" sz="quarter" idx="13" hasCustomPrompt="1"/>
</p:nvPr>
```

I'm trying to get the `idx` value (13, in this case).

The statement I'm using looks like this, so far (I'm saying "so far" because I don't know how to finish the statement):

```
var index = shape.NonVisualShapeProperties.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties. <-???
```

At this point in the code, I have the shape I want, I just can't figure out how to get the placeholder values using Open Office SDK. I guess I could just treat it as plain old XML and get it by element name, but I figured the OOXML SDK would have some method built-in for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do this:

`index = int.Parse(shape.NonVisualShapeProperties.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties.PlaceholderShape.Index);`

I was using `NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties` when I should have been using `ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties`.